# Get specific text from huge string

Tags: java, string, api

I'm calling an API and getting a huge String of text back (thousands of words in most cases).

All I want to do is get the thumbnail_url.

Here's a sample:

```
  "thumbnail_url": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/4171SQ7VC4L.jpg", "type": "rich", "thumbnail_height": 379
```

So all I want is http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/4171SQ7VC4L.jpg from this example. Any idea?

**EDIT** - thumnail_url is in the middle of the big block of text, so I need to search for "thumbnail_url" or something, right?

Comment: That looks like JSON so all you need to do is parse it into an object and pluck out the property you want.

Comment: I'm using this in a java class though if that makes any difference. I kind of want to just put it in a String and then put it in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use external JSON Library such as GSON - i think by google or [This](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) which is also fine

and use it in such way :

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(yourString);
System.out.println("url=" + json.get("thumbnail_url"));
```

Comment: Never used JSON before, is this a good way to go about it rather than using .indexOf and .substring?

Comment: its the best - you are given Json string then use Json parses

Comment: @user3504452 nothing more ;)

Comment: Thought JSONObject was something I needed to import in java, oops.

Comment: @user3504452 well its external library so yeah u need to import

Answer (score 0):

Unclever answer with a RegExp :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"thumbnail_url\": \"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourBigString);

List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    urls.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: althouth this probably works - why making things complicated ;) ?

Comment: The first word is "unclever", so I think he's pretty clear on it :)

Comment: we dont know if the string is really a JSON or if what looks like a JSON is par of a bigger non-JSON string. And I say "unclever" ;)